# Extract all valid email addresses with Regex JS

Tags: regex

I want to extract all valid email addresses from a given text.

Emails are considered to be in format user @ host, where:

•   *user* is a sequence of letters and digits, where '.', '-' and '_' can appear between them.

•   *host* is a sequence of at least two words, separated by dots '.'. Each word is sequence of letters and can have hyphens '-' between the letters, but ending with a letter.

•   Examples of valid emails:

- s.kiki@hotmail.co.uk
- no-reply@github-bg.com.uk.bg
- no_reply@github-bg.com.uk.bg

I wrote this regex:

```
/(?<!\S)[a-z0-9]+[\-\._]*[a-z0-9]+@[a-z]+\-*[a-z]+(\.[a-z0-9\-]+){1,}(?=\s|$)/g
```

But match and this case: suport@github.com**-**

How to get rid of the last '-' ?

Comment: Regex for emails are complicated. There are many rules about allowed special characters, string lengths. While you can do a basic email test it is better to use an existing library that has been extensively tested. Exame of rules: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address. Use something like yup.

Comment: Or if you just want basic example which excludes all special characters: /^[a-z]\w*(\.[a-z]\w*)*\@[a-z]\w*(\.[a-z]\w*)*$/

Comment: What are your arbitrary rules for a "valid" email? If you want to be compliant with the RFC then see https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/2191572

Comment: I have a task with this condition: Emails are considered to be in format <user>@<host>, where: 
• <user> is a sequence of letters and digits, where '.', '-' and '_' can appear between them.
• <host> is a sequence of at least two words, separated by dots '.'. Each word is sequence of letters and can have hyphens '-' between the letters, but ending with a letter.
• Examples of valid emails:  s.kiki@hotmail.co.uk , no-reply@github-bg.com.uk.bg , no_reply@github-bg.com.uk.bg

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the `-` at the end of your host words you can create two groups of character lists:
One that includes the minus and one excluding it.

You require the capture group that excludes the `-` to be matched at least once and the other one any number of times.

That can look like this:

```
([a-zA-Z-]*[a-zA-Z]+\.){1,}[a-zA-Z-]*[a-zA-Z]+$
```

See https://regex101.com/r/LwHlU3/1 for what this does and does not match.